# Tiniest Java web server

Tags: java, webserver

I need the simplest web server to write a minimal web interface for an application. It should be something really featureless like Webrick from Ruby's standard library or BaseHTTPServer from Python's standard library, just a way to keep a server listening to a port and respond to GET requests with a string.

Thanks

Comment: This Question belongs in the [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## NanoHTTPD

Try [*NanoHTTPD*](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd). I have been using it for [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) development.

> *NanoHTTPD* is a light-weight HTTP server designed for embedding in other applications, released under a Modified BSD licence.

Comment: While NanoHTTPD is great for it's simplicity, note that it is not really maintained anymore and that there are still some open issues in the project.

Answer (score 9):

## Jetty

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) is what I personally prefer. It has small memory footprint, easily integrated with Eclipse, can be used as Maven embedded server.

Optionally you can see [Mini Web Server](http://www.jibble.org/miniwebserver/)

Answer (score 8):

## `com.sun.net.httpserver`

Very *cheap* alternative:

Sun's Java comes with its own [httpserver package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html) since java 1.6

> Provides a simple high-level Http server API, which can be used to build embedded HTTP servers. Both "http" and "https" are supported.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say if you wanted it single-threaded or multi-threaded, so here's both:

[Single-threaded Java web server](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/javawebserver.php)

[Multi-threaded Java web server](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/Webserver/)

Answer (score 3):

## Spark

> A micro framework for creating web applications in Kotlin and Java 8 with minimal effort

For Java 8 and later:
http://sparkjava.com/

Answer (score 2):

## Takes Framework

Try [Takes Framework](http://www.takes.org/):

```
new FtBasic(new TkText("hello, world!"), 8080).start(Exit.NEVER);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Project Grizzly

I recommend [Grizzly Web Server](http://grizzly.java.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Winstone: http://winstone.sourceforge.net (330KB executable Jar, one-line file server, TLS, AJP support, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [JLHTTP - The Java Lightweight HTTP Server](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jlhttp) will suit your needs - it was created with exactly this kind of use-case in mind. I would know, since I'm the author :-)

It's intentionally written as a single source file for easy embedding in any project, or as a ~50K jar (~35K stripped) with no dependencies. It is not just 'a server listening to a port' or 'featureless' as OP requested, but does strive to be RFC-compliant and includes extensive documentation and many useful features while keeping bloat to a minimum. It tries to keep the gentle balance between being tiny and being useful.

Among the features are virtual hosts, parameter parsing (query string or x-www-form-urlencoded body), multipart/form-data handling for file uploads, download continuation, serving files from disk, HTTPS, gzip/deflate compression, generated directory index, welcome pages, support for all HTTP methods, multi-threaded connection handling, multiple context handlers via API or annotations, etc.

I think it's a reasonable feature set for ~3K lines of code (of which almost half are documentation). If even this is too much for you, you can easily customize it and strip out the parts you don't need.

Have a look - I hope it fits your requirements :-)