# What's the simplest way to setup a web server in java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have server daemons running on several machines. I decide to expose the internal stats of the server daemons for monitoring and statistic, using HTTP protocol.

So, what's the simplest way to do this?

- The less 3rd-party jar dependencies, the better.
- The lighter the framework is, the better.
- The less complexity, the better.

Comment: @CoolBeans i think they are a bit complex and heavy for my application. I just wanna get some internal stat message via visit url like: http://server.ip/metrix-name .

Comment: What functionality do you need?  Servlet container?? You could have a a look at [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) or [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) which has library that can be used to build a HTTP server from...

Comment: You could also take a look at the [Inbuilt HTTP Server](http://alistairisrael.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/functional-http-testing-with-sun-java-6-httpserver/) in Java 6

Comment: possible duplicate of [simple HTTP server in Java using only Java SE API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api)

Comment: Have you considered JMX?  It's pretty simple and close to what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tiniest Java web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572127/tiniest-java-web-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stats are a small number of fairly basic statistics, and you aren't wedded to the HTTP server concept, use JMX.  I used it to instrument a daemon process and it was pretty simple.  You can monitor remotely (on another computer) via an ugly, but serviceable UI.

[Here's a tutorial instrumenting a web server app](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09196/index.html?ca=drs)  Probably very close to what you want.

[Here's a StackOverflow link on remote monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834581/remote-jmx-connection)

Comment: +1, JMX is a lot easier if an HTTP server isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The lightest weight java webserver I know of is [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). If you use maven, you don't have to add any dependencies to your project, just add jetty as a plugin:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
 </plugin>
```

then you can just call

```
 mvn jetty:run
```

at the command line. a lot of open source projects ship with a jetty server embedded, including hadoop.